# Unix script to launch multple projects from terminal

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, scripting, tabs

#### What I have?

- I have **multiple projects** in Nodejs and Angularjs, which are **dependent** on each other.
- I used to **`cd`** to each project directory and run the corresponding command for that project.
- For this I need to **remember which command should I use** to run each project.
- Each project might require **multiple commands** to run. (eg: launch ui and backend)
- All projects are in same directory.

#### What I want?

- I want a script which would open **unique terminal tabs for each project** I want to run.
- Also tab name should resemble **project name and command run in its title**

Answer (score 0):

### script

```sh
# Set your parent directory, where all projects would be present
projDir='/home/yatishbalaji/projects/'

# Declare list of projects along with the command to run.
# If u want to run multiple commands per project (eg: ui and backend), 
# seperate commands with `;`, and this script will open them in different tabs

declare -A MYMAPS=(
["manage"]="grunt serve"  
["hire"]="gulp serve" 
["billing"]="npm run startApi;npm run startUI;npm run startLambda"
["algo"]="npm run dev"
);

launchCmd=''

for app in "$@"; do
        STR=${MYMAPS[$app]}
    IFS=';'
    read -ra commandArr <<< "$STR"

    for command in ${commandArr[*]}; do
            cmd='cd '$projDir$app' && '$command
        launchCmd+=(--tab -t "$app=>$command" -e "bash -c '$cmd';bash")
#       launchCmd+=(--tab -t "$app=>$command" --working-directory="$projDir$app" -e "bash -c '$command';bash")
    done
done
gnome-terminal "${launchCmd[@]}";
# mate-terminal "${launchCmd[@]}"
exit 0;
```

### How to use ?

Pass project names(you want to open), as parameters to your script

`bash ~/launchApps.sh manage billing`